# Undefined symbol unixd_config

Tags: apache, siteminder

Whenever I try to load the libmod_sm22.so or libmodsm_20.so module into apache-2.4.6, I am getting error as shown below :

> httpd: Syntax error on line 65 of httpd.conf: Cannot load /opt/software/siteminder/waR12cr009/webagent/bin/libmod_sm22.so into server: /opt/software/siteminder/waR12cr009/webagent/bin/libmod_sm22.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config

From the apache documentation I found that apache-2.4.6 API has changed `unixd_config` to `ap_unixd_config`.
But the `libmod_sm20.so / libmod_sm22.so` is still looking for `unixd_config`

In the apache’s include folder I have found references for the unixd_config symbol as shown below

```
============================================================================
[apache@VDCLL1828 include]$ cat ap_mmn.h |grep 'unixd_config'
* 20071108.9 (2.3.0-dev)  Add chroot support to unixd_config
* 20101106.2 (2.3.9-dev)  Add suexec_disabled_reason field to ap_unixd_config
*                         add ap_unixd_config.group_name

[apache@VDCLL1828 include]$ cat unixd.h |grep 'unixd_config'
} unixd_config_rec;
AP_DECLARE_DATA extern unixd_config_rec ap_unixd_config;
===========================================================
```

I didn’t try to change these references as these are not completely related to what I am looking for & in turn this may break other working things if I mess up.

At this point I have two options to make siteminder working in apache-2.4.6

1. Prepare the libmod_sm22.so that it looks for ap_unixd_config instead of unixd_config (If possible)
2. Look out for a patch to apache 2.4.6 api .

Any thoughts around this are highly appreciated.